# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'message' before initialization

Tags: javascript, variables, discord.js

I use discord.js library to make my first discord bot this is my code for now:

```
console.clear()
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const cooldowns = new Discord.Collection();
const client = new Discord.Client();
    var ID = '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 10)
    var logChannelID = 123456789
    var bannedWords = ['idiot', 'idk']
    client.on("message", async message => {
                    if (message.author.bot) return;
                    if (!message.guild) return;
    
                    for (let word in bannedWords) {
                        const delMessageEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                            .setColor('#FF0000')
                            .setTitle('Wolfram AutoMod')
                            .setDescription('')
                            .addFields({
                                name: 'Guild / Server:',
                                value: `\`${message.guild.name}\``,
                            }, {
                                name: 'Channel:',
                                value: `\`${message.channel.name}\``,
                            }, {
                                name: 'Full Message:',
                                value: `\`${message.content}\``,
                            }, {
                                name: 'Detected Word:',
                                value: `\`${bannedWords[word]}\``,
                            }, )
                            .setTimestamp()
                            .setFooter(`${ID} | ${name} v${version} - by @AnonHexo#3411`)
                        const message = `Deleted message from: ${message.author}\n Channel: ${message.channel.name}\n Full message: ${message.content}\n Sent at: ${new Date(message.createdAt)}\n Detected word: ${bannedWords[word]}\n Session ID: ${ID}\n`
                        if (message.content.includes(bannedWords[word])) {
                            message.author.send(delMessageEmbed);
                            console.log(message)
                            client.channels.cache.get(logChannelID).send(adminDelMessageEmbed)
                            fs.appendFile(`./sessions/${ID}.dat`, `${message}`, () => {})
                            message.delete()
                        }
                    }
```

but I get this error when i try to run it: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'message' before initialization` 
I already red all anwsers talking about this problem but I still can't find out how to fix it... 
 
pls **help!**

Comment: You use the same variable name twice (`message`). As you declare `message` again, JS will try to use `message` from `const message = \`Deleted message from: ${message.author} ...` when looking for `message.author`. Try to rename it.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros THANKS! It woks fine now, a really big big thank!